# Qt plugins: is there a way to list all interfaces a plugin implements?

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, moc

I have a Qt application that allows custom plugins (loaded with `QPluginLoader`), and these plugins can implement some interfaces, and declare with the `Q_INTERFACES()` macro.

If you look at Qt's documentation linked below, I'm talking about the "low-level" API:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html

**Now, this is my question**: after I load a plugin with `QPluginLoader`, is there a way to enumerate all the interfaces it implements? Basically, is there a way to enumerate what the plugin declares in the `Q_INTERFACES()` macro from the main app loading the plugin?

The application currently works with both Qt4 and Qt5, but a solution that works only with Qt5 would be acceptable as well.

Comment: Qt definitely creates meta data for the interfaces, but I don't seem to find any way to iterate through it.

Comment: @ddriver The meta data is created in a very implicit fashion: moc generates code that lets you cast the `QObject` to an instance of the interface, iff you know the interface's name. The data is not retained in any other fashion: there's no list of interfaces anywhere :(

Comment: Well, it does have to store the actual strings for the names, since the meta system works with string literals and does runtime lookups, it is just a serious omission in the design of the meta system that this data is not structured in some more useful way. I also don't like the fact it is generated for everything, it would be better if you could specify what kind of meta data you want for a particular object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Qt doesn't explicitly keep the list of interfaces :(

The best you can do is to attempt to cast the `QObject * instance()` returned by the plugin loader to a given interface given either using a class name or using its IID, using `qt_metacast`, i.e. `loader.instance()->qt_metacast("IFoo")`. If the result is non-zero, then the given class implements the interface.

Alternatively, you can add each interface as class info, and you can then enumerate them:

```
class Impl : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_INTERFACES(IFoo IBar)
  Q_CLASSINFO("Interface", "IFoo")
  Q_CLASSINFO("Interface", "IBar")
}

QStringList interfaces(QObject * obj) {
  QStringList result;
  auto count = obj->metaObject()->classInfoCount();
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    auto info = obj->metaObject()->classInfo(i);
    if (strcmp(info.name(), "Interface") == 0)
      result << QString::fromLatin1(info.value());
  }
  return result;
}
```

If you wish to depend on this functionality, you'd want to modify your copy of `moc` to generate relevant classinfo automatically from `Q_INTERFACES`. IIRC it's just a few lines worth of a change, I've done something like that at some point.

Comment: If you are the one who gets to implement the plugins, you might as well put a `virtual QStringList interfaces()` in a `InterfaceInfo` interface and include that in each plugin and manually implement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's too bad that Qt doesn't provide a way to enumerate interfaced. For context, my goal was to create a map from all available interfaces to all the plugin that implement them, so anybody who wants to interact with a given interface could query all the available plugins. This way, I could (among other things) implement a plugin dependency system.

Comment: I guess, then, I have two options: either I freeze the list of available interfaces, and for each plugin, try each interface one by one and see if I can cast the plugin object to it, or I use the CLASSINFO as suggested (and yes, our team is also the one writing the plugins). I'm definitely not patching moc though, no resources to maintain that ;)